# operator does not exist: record = character varying in postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting below error while executing the following query using JPA native query

Error :

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: record = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 228
```

Query:

```
select ar.adm_rule_id 
from adm_promo.adm_rule ar,
     adm_promo.adm_non_comp_rule ac,
     adm_promo.adm_rule_hier_level ah 
where ar.rule_type =? 
  and ar.sales_org_id=? 
  and (ac.promo_market_id,ah.level_id) in (?) 
  and ar.adm_rule_id=ac.adm_rule_id 
  and ar.adm_rule_id=ah.adm_rule_id 
  and ar.delete_f='N' 
  and (ar.eff_end_date>=(?) and ar.eff_start_date<=(?)) 
  and ar.dist_channel=?
```

But I'm getting result for the same query with actual inputs, when I tried in PostgreSql
Query with inputs:

```
select ar.adm_rule_id 
from adm_promo.adm_rule ar,
     adm_promo.adm_non_comp_rule ac,
     adm_promo.adm_rule_hier_level ah 
where ar.rule_type =1 
  and ar.sales_org_id=1 
 and (ac.promo_market_id,ah.level_id) in ((9,63)) 
  and ar.adm_rule_id=ac.adm_rule_id 
  and ar.adm_rule_id=ah.adm_rule_id 
  and ar.delete_f='N' 
  and (ar.eff_end_date>=('2020-09-29') 
  and ar.eff_start_date<=('2020-10-17')) 
  and ar.dist_channel=1
```

I couldn't find the issue exactly, team please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has a problem with this:
`(ac.promo_market_id,ah.level_id) in (?)`

Try to cast it, as suggested in the error, by changing the query to:
`(ac.promo_market_id,ah.level_id) in (?::record)`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the fact that it says "position 228" and scrolling along to that character of your query puts you near this:

```
(ac.promo_market_id,ah.level_id) in ((9,63))
```

but your template for the query has this

```
(ac.promo_market_id,ah.level_id) in (?)
```

It might well be that you are providing the wrong sort of data there. It is unlikely that your database driver supports parameterized lists of values (to match your "IN" clause). You are probably ending up with some quoted text, which Postgres is treating as "character varying" which of course fails to match.